# Change ListView DataSourceID when page load?

Tags: asp.net, listview

this my project i have a listview .that show comment of article or handwritten.
i have two sqldatasource with number 2(for article) and 3(for handwritten).
i want to change data source id when page load and show other comment .
default listview datasourceid is sqldatasource2 and it work ,but when change sqldatasource2 to sqldatasource3 they did not work.
this is select command of sqldatasource2

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$
       ConnectionStrings:myconnection_sql %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [date], [text]
        FROM [comment] WHERE ([idarticle] = @idarticle)">
```

this is select command of sqldatasource3

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$
       ConnectionStrings:myconnection_sql %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [date], [text]
        FROM [comment] WHERE ([idhandwritten] = @idarticle)">
```

this is page_load code:

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {


        try
        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("id"));



            SqlConnection con = new  
                 SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["myconnection_sql"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select type from article_handwritten where
            id=@id");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            string type = dt.Rows[0]["type"].ToString();
            if (type == "Article")
            {
                ListView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
                ListView1.DataBind();

            }
            else if (type == "handwritten")
            {
                ListView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3";
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: what does it show in `ListView1` on second condition?

Comment: i have one table for comment with two  filed.when user add comment for article i give id of article and store in idarticle filed and when add comment for handwritten save to idhandwritten and set null other field

Comment: what your `type` variable consists on second condition???? "handwritten" or "Handwritten" ???